# My travis-ci yml for docker seems a little verbose - am I using docker run incorrectly?

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I am ready for some serious trolling here, but I am not sure where else to look. If you feel like helping me out thanks, otherwise a kind nod towards a better source of answers would be greatly appreciated.
I have a .yml file for use on Travis-CI and I am making use of a custom docker image. I have included the file below and can't help but feel I am doing it the hard way. All suggestions would are welcome.

```
sudo: required

language: c

services:
    - docker

before_install:
    - docker pull kaixhin/cuda
    - docker run --name="cuda_7.5" kaixhin/cuda /bin/sh -c "sudo apt-get update"
    - docker commit cuda_7.5 kaixhin/cuda:latest
    - docker rm cuda_7.5 
    - docker run --name="cuda_7.5" kaixhin/cuda /bin/sh -c "sudo apt-get install -y cmake"
    - docker commit cuda_7.5 kaixhin/cuda:latest
    - docker rm cuda_7.5
    - mkdir  /home/travis/build/inJeans/cuda_dsmc/build

script:
    - docker run -v=/home/travis/build/inJeans/cuda_dsmc:/cuda_dsmc --name="cuda_7.5" kaixhin/cuda /bin/sh -c "cd /cuda_dsmc/build; cmake .."
    - docker commit cuda_7.5 kaixhin/cuda:latest
    - docker rm cuda_7.5
    - docker run -v=/home/travis/build/inJeans/cuda_dsmc:/cuda_dsmc --name="cuda_7.5" kaixhin/cuda /bin/sh -c "cd /cuda_dsmc/build; make" 
    - docker commit cuda_7.5 kaixhin/cuda:latest
    - docker rm cuda_7.5
    - docker run -v=/home/travis/build/inJeans/cuda_dsmc:/cuda_dsmc --name="cuda_7.5" kaixhin/cuda /bin/sh -c "cd /cuda_dsmc/build; make test" 
    - docker commit cuda_7.5 kaixhin/cuda:latest
    - docker rm cuda_7.5
```

I am making changes to the local directory outside my docker container and I want those changes to persist, that is why I am constantly committing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a Dockerfile, that's a travis-ci config file.

I've not tested this, but if you wanted consolidate the `before_install` and `script` to become a single Dockerfile it might look like this.

```
FROM kaixhin/cuda
RUN /bin/sh -c "sudo apt-get update \
    && sudo apt-get install -y cmake" \
RUN mkdir -p /cuda_dsmc/build \
    && curl -SL http://path.to.your/code.tgz \
    | tar -xJC /cuda_dsmc \
    && /cuda_dsmc/build
    && cmake .. \
    && build \ 
    && make \
    && make test
```

Using Docker Hub's automated builds, you could have a custom image with your code ready to pull and test in travis-ci.

Further reading:

- Dockerfile best practice: http://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices
- Docker Hub automated builds: http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerrepos/#automated-builds